# I want to take an element from a list and put it in a new list

Tags: python

`lines = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9]]`, where node is a list of Each of them contains two numbers, but the left one is the parent node and the right one is the child node. The parent node is fixed at 0. The lines list shows that 0 (parent node) is connected to 1, 2, and 3 (child nodes), 1 to 4, 2 to 5 and 6, and 3 to 7, 8, and 9.
We want to connect the numbers 0→1→4, 0→2→5, 0→2→6, 0→3→7, 0→3→8, 0→3→9, and finally `[0, [1, [4]], [2, [5], [6]], [3, [7], [8], [9]]`.

In the current code, printing the result would result in `[[0], [1, [4]], [2, [5, 6]], [3, [7, 8, 9]]]`, possibly because `node.append(j[1])` has `[5, 6], [7, 8, 9]` in the node list as they are listed.
Is there any way to make this print as `[0, [1, [4]], [2, [5], [6]], [3, [7], [8], [9]]]`?

```
lines = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9]]

result = []
node_n = []
for i in lines:
    node = list()
    for j in lines:
        if i[0] == j[0]:
            node.append(j[1])
            # print(node)
    node_list = [i[0],node]    
    if node_list not in result:
        result.append(node_list)
result.sort()
del result[0][1]
print(result)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _connect_? Can you explain why `[0, [1, [4]], [2, [5], [6]], [3, [7], [8], [9]]` represents this connection? Also, can you provide some context? Why are you trying to get this output? Maybe there is another way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by: "I want to take an element from a list and put it in a new list".  Which list are you using as input, what list are you creating, what do you expect the output to be and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just correct the code as follows:

```
lines = [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,7],[3,8],[3,9]]

result = []
node_n = []
for i in lines:
    node = []
    for j in lines:
        if i[0] == j[0]:
            node.append(j[1])
    node_list = [i[0],node]    
    if node_list not in result:
        result.append(node_list)
result.sort()

# build the tree
tree = [result[0][0]]
for i in result[1:]:
    children = []
    for j in i[1]:
        children.append([j])
    tree.append([i[0]] + children)

print(tree)
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a graph traversal for this output. Use `networkx` to build a graph from the `lines` list and then you need to recursively traverse (in a depth first fashion) to build the list. There is no ready method (api) available in `networkx` to get the desired output. One way is below:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(lines)
def construct(lst, G, node, visited):
    if node in visited:
        return lst
    visited.add(node)
    lst.append(node)
    for nbr in nx.neighbors(G, node):
        if nbr not in visited:
            lst.append(construct([], G, nbr, visited))
    return lst
print(construct([], G, 0, set()))

[0, [1, [4]], [2, [5], [6]], [3, [7], [8], [9]]]
```

The time complexity is O(V + E) where V is number of nodes and E is length of the `lines` list.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def nodes(n):
    return [n]+[nodes(y) for [x,y] in lines if x==n]
nodes(0)
# → [0, [1, [4]], [2, [5], [6]], [3, [7], [8], [9]]]
```

It returns a list made of node n, and of all the list representing subtrees for the successors of n (obtained recursively)

So, for `nodes(0)` it returns `[0] + [nodes(1), nodes(2), nodes(3)]`

And `nodes(1)` is `[1] + [nodes(4)]`

And `nodes(4)` is just `[4]`

Etc.

### Edit: 1 lines traversal

Indeed, this method read the whole `lines` several times.
One solution is to read it once, and build a dict from it, associating each node to a list of childs, and build then from this dict.

```py
d={}
for [x,y] in lines:
    d[x] = d.get(x, []) + [y]

def nodes(n):
    return [n] + [nodes(i) for i in d.get(n, [])]
nodes(0)
# → [0, [1, [4]], [2, [5], [6]], [3, [7], [8], [9]]]
```

Maybe not as efficient as using a dedicated module. But same complexity. And using pure python.

Comment: This will work but need to traverse the list multiple times unnecessarily just to find the 'x'.